# What is centos /root/core.* files? they eat my hard disk till it is full

Tags: core-dump

I have a vps server with 130GB hard disk. Recently, the server is crash down, I access ssh and use `dh -h`,

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs             130G  130G   0  99% /
none                  2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
```

Then use `du -sh /*` I find `root fold` with 59GB. then `du -sh /root/*`, a long list with some file like

```
...
43M     /root/core.7856
59M     /root/core.7859
59M     /root/core.7862
43M     /root/core.7883
43M     /root/core.7885
43M     /root/core.7889
59M     /root/core.7892
59M     /root/core.7904
43M     /root/core.7906
59M     /root/core.7913
43M     /root/core.7915
59M     /root/core.7940
59M     /root/core.7942
43M     /root/core.7947
43M     /root/core.7951
...
```

I access my server with `fileZilla`, 1204 core.* files create in recent 3 days.

So what is centos /root/core.* files? How are they created? Could I delete them without damage my server? And how to avoid them to be created again?

**FIX THE PROBLEM**

The problem caused by linux mail system. I changed `/etc/mail/trusted-users` permission in `etc/mail/submit.cf` line 552. then, no `/root/core.* files` be created again.

Comment: These look like core dump. Is your system crashing?

Comment: You might also keep a couple of *core* file for some post-mortem analysis, just to know **what** crashed so hard/often. Why is another story though ...

Comment: @edvinas.me, Thanks, i have deleted them now i can reboot my server . how to check my system is crashing? It seems good, I can open my page, all the thing looks good. but the core.* files still created automaticly.

Comment: @Ouki, how to analysis them? Any log record them? How can i know ahy are they created? Thanks.

Comment: See Andreas Wiese answer for some starting point. It is easier to guess through logs than to really do post-mortem analysis of core files, but you can still keep a couple of them just in case ...

Comment: @Ouki, so which log file should i checked? thanks again.

Comment: `/var/log/messages*` (`dmesg` being a part of them) are always a good start. Then maybe your web error log files ...

Comment: @Ouki, no, the last log in messages is 1 day before. Now i see some problem in `maillog` `NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): /etc/mail/submit.cf: line 552: fileclass: cannot open '/etc/mail/trusted-users': World writable directory`. Is it could be cause the main problem?

Comment: In my case my server was running out of RAM due to an anti-virus

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are so-called [core dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump). Some signals' default handler besides killing the receiver of the signal is writing out the memory contents and process state at the time of death for post-mortem analysis.  Unless you're planning to dissect those files you can safely remove them.

You could also inhibit the creation of core dumps by setting the appropriate resource limit to `0` (this is done by setting the `core` item in `/etc/security/limits.conf` to `0`).

You should note that the fact that your system creates those files rather rapidly should alarm you that there's something not going too well because some process regularly dies in a non-intended way.  This could be caused by a buggy (automatically respawning) program or be caused by more serious problems like memory defect.  You might want to look into your log files and `dmesg` output to get a hold on that.

Comment: thanks for your answer, which log file can i check? and if i set `/etc/security/limits.conf` to `0`, is it safe for my server?

Comment: Switching off core dump generation is completely safe.  But you should understand that this core dumps aren't your real problem but just a symptom.  You should start looking at the files in `/var/log` and see if there's something logged about crashed processes.  Another approach would be calling `dmesg` and look what the kernrel has to say (I'd guess that the offending process would have be killed by `SIGBUS` or `SIGSEGV`, at least the latter one — segmentation faults — are usually logged by the kernel).

Comment: find something could be make the problem in  `maillog` `NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): /etc/mail/submit.cf: line 552: fileclass: cannot open '/etc/mail/trusted-users': World writable directory`

Comment: I would suggest fixing this disturbing "world writable directory" problem then : `sudo chmod o-w /etc/mail/trusted-users`. You may want to check your permissions in general, actually...

Comment: And to emphasize, this is most probably not the problem you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

They are dumps of the memory core of programs that have crashed while being run by the root user.  Unless you plan on debugging them, you can delete them.

Comment: thanks , i have deleted them, and now i can restart my server. but how are they created? Which log can i check? and how to stop them be created?

Answer (score 1):

[Core dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) are crash dumps. The program `file` with one of the core files as argument might tell you which program keeps crashing.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the core files being created again with:

```
ulimit -c 0
```

This limits the maximum size of core files created to 0.

See bash man page for further details.